# Cannot retrieve ExperienceBundle file for a community, an error "ExperienceBundle Metadata API doesn't support the template of" is shown

Tags: community, metadata-api

I have enabled Enable ExperienceBundle Metadata API and tried to retrieve a Experience Bundle file but obtained an error

```
ExperienceBundle Metadata API doesn't support the template of Partners1.
```

I can't find any piece of the information in [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_experiencebundle.htm) about the list of the supported templates which can be retrieved by the ExperienceBundle API.

Comment: What is your template type? Not that vf templates are not supported?

Comment: I was doing a trailhead module https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/identity_external/identity_external_community and this community has an Aloha Template. But I can't find any information that Aloha or VF template are not supported by ExperienceBundle Metadata API

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the Experience Bundle Metadata API documentation carefully,

> Developers can quickly update and deploy one or more Lightning communities programmatically using their preferred development tools.

It clearly says **Lightning communities**. This means aloha or Visualforce communities are not supported.

Maybe the documentation can be made more clear by mentioning that Visualforce communities are not supported!

Comment: I am new at Experience Cloud, so I don't really know which community templates are Lightning and which are not. Thanks for clarifying this.